# WPF TreeView, Entity Framework and HierarchicalDataTemplate with nested child lists

Tags: wpf, frameworks, treeview, entity, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I'm trying to bind a complex data structure to a WPF TreeView using HierarchicalDataTemplate(s). The collections of data is being stored in my ViewModel as a IList of MyObject - MyObject has several properties several of which are lists in their own regard.

The output I'm trying to achieve is something along the lines of:

```
+ MyObject 1 <br>
  + List1 <br>
    - List 1 Object 1 <br>
    - List 1 Object 2 <br>
  + List2 <br>
    - List 2 Object 1 <br>
    - List 2 Object 2 <br>
+ MyObject 2 <br>
  + List1 <br>
    - List 1 Object 1 <br>
    - List 1 Object 2 <br>
  + List2 <br>
    - List 2 Object 1 <br>
    - List 2 Object 2 <br>
```

However I can't seem to get the composite collection I've seen mentioned a few places working -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did something similar to this.  Unfortunately, you can't do this directly, as the TreeViewItem only accepts one collection for its ItemsSource.

What I did was create a model that exposes the contents in the way the TreeView requires.

```
public class MyObjectWrapper
{
  public MyObject Target {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable MyLists
  {
    get
    {
      yield return Target.List1;
      yield return Target.List2;
    } 
  }
}
```

where MyObject is defined as:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public List1CollectionType List1 {get;private set;}
    public List2CollectionType List2 {get;private set;}
}
```

Your bindings are then

- TreeViewItem : MyObjectWrapper

  - ItemsSource : MyLists
  - TreeViewItem : List1CollectionType

    - ItemsSource : {Binding} (binds directly to the datacontext)
  - TreeViewItem : List2CollectionType

    - ItemsSource : {Binding}

You'll need a DataTemplate for MyObjectWrapper, List1CollectionType, and List2CollectionType.

Comment: Could you clarify what `Target` is referring to? Thank you for revisiting.

Comment: @UB3571 target is the hypothetical object containing the lists that are to be shown in the treeview